# Create multiple tables/grids

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I've just started learning ASP.NET Core MVC based on this [first-mvc-app tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/)

I have a database table 'tblProducts' and I can create a single table listing all products using

**Model**:

```
public class tblProducts
{
    //SQL table is named tblProducts

    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; } //<<Want separate tables split by this field
}
```

**View**:

```
@model IEnumerable<LearnMVC.Models.tblProducts>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Field1)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Field2)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Product)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Field1)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Field2)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Edit</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Details</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Contoller**: Default MVC Controller with views, using Entity Framework

```
public class tblProductsController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public tblProductsController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;    
    }

    // GET: tblProducts
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await _context.tblProducts.ToListAsync());
    }

    // GET: tblProducts/Details/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var tblProducts = await _context.tblProducts.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
        if (tblProducts == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(tblProducts);
    }

    // GET: tblProducts/Create
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: tblProducts/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ID,Date,Field1,Field2,Product")] tblProducts tblProducts)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(tblProducts);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(tblProducts);
    }

    // GET: tblProducts/Edit/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var tblProducts = await _context.tblProducts.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
        if (tblProducts == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return View(tblProducts);
    }

    // POST: tblProducts/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("ID,Date,Field1,Field2,Product")] tblProducts tblProducts)
    {
        if (id != tblProducts.ID)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                _context.Update(tblProducts);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!tblProductsExists(tblProducts.ID))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(tblProducts);
    }

    // GET: tblProducts/Delete/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var tblProducts = await _context.tblProducts.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
        if (tblProducts == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(tblProducts);
    }

    // POST: tblProducts/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        var tblProducts = await _context.tblProducts.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
        _context.tblProducts.Remove(tblProducts);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    private bool tblProductsExists(int id)
    {
        return _context.tblProducts.Any(e => e.ID == id);
    }
}
```

**Data\ApplicationDbContext.cs**:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }

    public DbSet<tblProducts> tblProducts { get; set; }
}
```

Please can someone help explain (or know of any good tutorials) how I can create multiple tables based on the same model fields but each table is split by the column 'Product'?

Say there are 5 products, I would expect to see 5 tables all with the same fields Date, Field1, Field2 & Product, but the Product would be unique to each table.

I won't know up front how many products there are so need some logic to determine how many tables are required. As I'm new to this I'm unsure if I need multiple models or if something clever can be done in the controller or view as the data is all from the same table.

I've tried a few searches but they seem to be either non-mvc or based on multiple different models (eg this is similar but has different data sources per table http://www.compilemode.com/2016/09/show-multiple-table-data-on-view-in-asp-net-mvc.html)

**TL;DR**: What is the ASP.NET MVC way of displaying multiple tables split by field from a single database table?

Comment: What's the code for querying the database? That's where you would specify which product to "split" the data on.

Comment: Look into partial views and display templates.  Consider creating a View Model to transform your data for display in a way that makes sense to you.  Maybe group the data model entities by product.  Then your view could simply loop over your view model collection of products to display a table for each one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Updated the [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yZAjLH) to better reflect your requirement regarding not knowing how many tables you'll need - sorry, missed that the first time around. As before, the fiddle doesn't run, but it should give you a good idea of where to go with it.

Personally, I prefer not to have that sort of logic in the view, and it's certainly possible to move it back to the controller, but think of this as more a proof of concept.

Comment: Thanks for your help. How would I handle not knowing how many products there are? The `class IndexViewModel` in your example assumes there are 3 products hardocoded but it could be any number depending on what's returned from the db table.

Comment: Sorry, missed that requirement the first time around - updated my answer - hope it helps.

Comment: This is excellent and works well, thank you very much. The only change I've made is that you have 3 foreach loops in the view when only 2 are needed